# How to call a rest api for multiple databases?

Tags: rest, design-patterns, database-design, architecture

I have to create a RESTful API for a system which is maybe a bit unusual in the sense that each client using this system has their own database. (A client is like a company, with many users in it). So there is a master database which specifies, for each client, which database it must connect to. All clients databases are identical (except for the data of course).

I'm wondering how I should handle this... Normally, when an app consumes a Web API, you might have something like this:

Comment: Not sure if understand completely your question but probably the idea is if all databases have same schema, to send something like client id to each request, then the api should find from master source  and build the corresponding database connection string within the api and then query against that database, finally the api should return the data to the client